# Linux Bash reading input

Tags: linux, bash

I need to get input from a user in response to this:

> Enter your zip code, city, and state (in that order)

The line of code that I'm getting to get that input is:

```
read zipCode city state
```

However, if the city is more than one word, the whole thing gets screwed up.

My main question is, how do I get the first word that the user inputs into zipCode, the last one into state, and everything in between into city?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would attempt to separate the input with more than whitespace. If you need to have input performed in a single step by the user, you could delimit it by comma or something (heck, even standard postal format, ie `Baton Rouge, LA 70821`, would be easier to parse).

If there's no huge need to have all 3 items acquired in a single input, it would make sense to split this up into 3 inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble with white spaces, you can change IFS' (internal field separator) variable value to another separator character i.e. ':'

```
IFS=':'
echo "Insert zip code, city and state separated by :"
read zipCode city state
echo "Zip:"  $zipCode    
echo "City:" $city
echo "State:" $state
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide escaped input:

```
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~/Documents/code/py/pandas-3.3 ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹eval-3393@8a2f309› ‹pandas-3.3›
╰─$ read zipcode city state
asdf "New\ York\ City" asdf
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~/Documents/code/py/pandas-3.3 ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹eval-3393@8a2f309› ‹pandas-3.3›
╰─$ echo $city
"New York City"
```

However, *please* for the love of kittens do not make your users do this. Just ask for 3 different values:

```
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~/Documents/code/py/pandas-3.3 ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹eval-3393@8a2f309› ‹pandas-3.3›
╰─$ echo -en "City: " && read city
City: My Awesome City with ∂!
╭─phillip@phillip-laptop  ~/Documents/code/py/pandas-3.3 ‹ruby-1.9.3@global› ‹eval-3393@8a2f309› ‹pandas-3.3›
╰─$ echo $city
My Awesome City with ∂!
```

Repeat that for your other variables.